# how to get Captured image filepath and save to database?

Tags: android

I was wondering if someone could help me, my application currently takes pictures with multiple capture image buttons and I want to get the file path of each images taken and save it to the database. how would I go about doing this. I tried to save it to my database using `string name = fileuri.getpath` but that doesn't give the exact destination of the image taken.

```
else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE_2) {

             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String second_imagePath = fileUri.getPath();
                 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
                 // images
                 options.inSampleSize = 8;
                 final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(second_imagePath, options);
                 second_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         second_imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                         .show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are steps you need to follow, you need to pass image name before opening of intent

```
 String fileName = "some.jpg";  
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
 values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
 mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);  
 startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_PICTURE_INTENT);
```

Then on onActivityResult()

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
cursor.moveToFirst(); 
String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
```

Comment: hey so will the file path of the image be located in the captured Image Filepath and then i would get that string to save to my databse?

Comment: just to undertsand why do i need to pass the image a name?

Comment: because it will save your image data to the file and will named it whatever you pass to that string.

Comment: i added the code for onActivity result as you said, but now my image captured is not set on the imageview like before. but it prints outs the string for that image

Comment: you need to call `getData` method on onActivityResult() to get the bitmap of the captured image.

Comment: Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                 first_image.setImageBitmap(photo);    like this?